# Shell script which will create a text file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I need to write a shell script that will do the following: will allow to create a text file from the keyboard and would find out the file type.

Could you help me? Thank you

Comment: We're happy to help with technical questions, but we won't write code for you.  First show us what you've tried so far, or explain what documentation you're using and what parts of it don't make sense, and we'll work from there.

Comment: What do you mean by 'file type'?  If you are creating a text file, then surely the file type is 'text'.

Answer (score 0):

to create a text file from keyboard input, you can use

```
cat > yourfile
```

which will send everything you type to yourfile, until you type ctrl+D on an empty line. or else, you can use any text editor. In all cases, the user will need to know how to terminate the input.

Then, if you want to identify the content of this file, you might suppose that the first line is a shebang (typically :

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and analyse it.